# using sharepoint designer work flow ,move list items from one list to another list into specific group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have two lists. one is cricket.Another one is Football. In Cricket list, the items are grouped by Today,Tomorrow and next month. If i add any new item into football. That item should be moved to cricket list in the group of Today. can any body know plese tell me using share point designer workflow or suggest me which approach will be good ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create one additional column in Cricket list, exp. "Time". That should be choice column type, where options are Today, Tomorrow, Next month.

Create workflow on list Football, add Create Item in list, choose Cricket list and than fill columns you need/want and source should be columns of created item in Football list. Include item column Time and set it to value Today.